# How do I include all empty directory in a maven assembly?

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, maven-assembly-plugin

I want use maven-assembly-plugin.

**My assembly descriptor:**

```
   <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
   <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
            <filtered>false</filtered>
            <fileMode>744</fileMode>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
```

**On Windows 7 (local computer) is it OK!!!:**

```
folder1/*  (contains files)
folder2/*  (contains files)
folder3    (Empty directory)
```

**But on Ubuntu (Jenkins) is it KO!!!:**

```
folder1/*  (contains files)
folder2/*  (contains files)
           (Empty directory folder3 do not exist)
```

**Edit:**

My real problem is Git (do not find empty folder). I want find a smart workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I find a smart workaround for use maven-assembly-plugin + git:**

I make a directory stay empty (in the repository) is to create a `.gitignore` file inside that directory that contains four lines:

```
# Ignore everything in this directory
*
# Except this file
!.gitignore
```